# Not show the user information page if there is an ini file with all fields filled

Tags: inno-setup

I have a code on my page for information about the user that once filled writes the data written to an ini file.
Will always be to open the installer it is possible to read the file ini filling user data and are all filled back not to show the user information page?

in other words...
open the installer, the user information page fills the fields
[image]

```
// create the input query page
  InputPage := CreateInputQueryPage(wpWelcome, 'User Information',' Add the following information! ',' Please fill in the following fields to keep updated database users.');
  // add an edit box and remember its index; False means it is not a password edit
  //name
  EditIndex1 := InputPage.Add('Name:', False);

  // bind events to the just added edit box
  //InputPage.Edits[EditIndex1].OnChange := @MyEditChange;
  InputPage.Edits[EditIndex1].OnKeyPress := @MyEditKeyPress;

  //labels: SetBounds(aLeft, aTop, aWidth, aHeight);
  InputPage.PromptLabels[EditIndex1].SetBounds(10,40,90,20);
  InputPage.Edits[EditIndex1].SetBounds(100,40,240,40);
  InputPage.Edits[EditIndex1].MaxLength:=35

  //username
  EditIndex2 := InputPage.Add('Username:', False);
  InputPage.Values[EditIndex2]:= ExpandConstant('{username}');
  InputPage.PromptLabels[EditIndex2].SetBounds(10,65,90,20);
  InputPage.Edits[EditIndex2].SetBounds(100,65,60,40);
  InputPage.Edits[EditIndex2].MaxLength:=7
  InputPage.Edits[EditIndex2].ReadOnly:=true;
  InputPage.Edits[EditIndex2].Color:=clBtnFace;

  //hostname
  EditIndex3 := InputPage.Add('Computername:', False);
  InputPage.Values[EditIndex3]:= ExpandConstant('{computername}');
  InputPage.PromptLabels[EditIndex3].SetBounds(10,90,90,20);
  InputPage.Edits[EditIndex3].SetBounds(100,90,100,40);
  InputPage.Edits[EditIndex3].MaxLength:=15
  InputPage.Edits[EditIndex3].ReadOnly:=true;
  InputPage.Edits[EditIndex3].Color:=clBtnFace;

  //e-mail
  EditIndex4 := InputPage.Add('E-mail:', False);
  InputPage.PromptLabels[EditIndex4].SetBounds(10,115,90,20);
  InputPage.Edits[EditIndex4].SetBounds(100,115,130,40);
  InputPage.Edits[EditIndex4].OnKeyPress:=@isAt;

  //@
  EditIndex5 := InputPage.Add('@', False);
  InputPage.PromptLabels[EditIndex5].SetBounds(235,115+3,10,20);
  InputPage.Edits[EditIndex5].SetBounds(250,115,70,40);
  InputPage.Edits[EditIndex5].OnKeyPress:=@noAt;
  InputPage.Edits[EditIndex5].MaxLength:=10;
  InputPage.Edits[EditIndex5].Text:='';

  //phone
  EditIndex6 := InputPage.Add('Phone:', False);
  InputPage.Edits[EditIndex6].OnKeyPress:=@NumbersOnly;
  InputPage.PromptLabels[EditIndex6].SetBounds(10,140,90,20);
  InputPage.Edits[EditIndex6].SetBounds(100,140,80,40);
  InputPage.Edits[EditIndex6].MaxLength:=9

  //extension
  EditIndex7 := InputPage.Add('Extension:', False);
  InputPage.Edits[EditIndex7].OnKeyPress:=@NumbersOnly;
  InputPage.PromptLabels[EditIndex7].SetBounds(10,165,90,20);
  InputPage.Edits[EditIndex7].SetBounds(100,165,60,40);
  InputPage.Edits[EditIndex7].MaxLength:=5

  //mobile
  EditIndex8 := InputPage.Add('Mobile:', False);
  InputPage.Edits[EditIndex8].OnKeyPress:=@NumbersOnly;
  InputPage.PromptLabels[EditIndex8].SetBounds(10,190,90,20);
  InputPage.Edits[EditIndex8].SetBounds(100,190,80,40);
  InputPage.Edits[EditIndex8].MaxLength:=9

end;
```

and creates the INI file

```
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  I: Integer;
  FileName, DateTime: String;

begin
DateTime:=GetDateTimeString('dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn', '-', ':');

For I:=0 to WizardForm.ComponentsList.Items.Count - 1 do
      If WizardForm.ComponentsList.Checked[I] then
  // if the installation has just finished, save the edit box text into a file

    case CurStep of
        ssInstall :
      SaveStringToFile(ExpandConstant('C:\dir\User.ini'), '[Date/Time] ' + DateTime + #13#10 + '[Version/Build] 2.4_4.2.3_rev4_25Jul14' + #13#10 + '[Name] ' + InputPage.Edits[EditIndex1].Text + #13#10 + '[Username] ' + InputPage.Edits[EditIndex2].Text + #13#10 + '[Computername] ' + InputPage.Edits[EditIndex3].Text + #13#10 + '[E-mail] ' + InputPage.Edits[EditIndex4].Text +
      '@' + InputPage.Edits[EditIndex5].Text + #13#10 + '[Phone] ' + InputPage.Edits[EditIndex6].Text + #13#10 + '[Extension] ' + InputPage.Edits[EditIndex7].Text + #13#10 + '[Mobile] ' + InputPage.Edits[EditIndex8].Text + #13#10 + #13#10, True)
  end;
end;
```

[image]

the next time you run the installer it reads the information from the ini and if the fields are not filled 7 shows the user information page.

can help me? Tanks.

Comment: Do you need to store that info into the file ? I'm asking because there is a built-in mechanism for storing custom data (through the `RegisterPreviousData` event method).

Comment: Yup. he is already stored in the directory of the installation ini file which was intended to make the installer when installing a second time to read the data inside the ini file. 

how can I use what I have seen RegisterPreviousData only reads the unistall, can you help me?

Comment: TLama, I saw the use of loadfile savefile and how can I use? 
As I can during the installation read the data stored in a file? 

ie: I wrote my name in the 1st field and finished the installation. 
The second time I installed, my program read what I wrote in the 1st field in the first installation. 

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Minor point, but that's not an INI file. It will be FAR easier to parse if you make it actually use the INI file format.

Comment: The basic summary of what you need to do is check of the file exists during loading (where you call `CreateInputQueryPage`). If it does, read each value and populate the controls (if needed), and set a global variable that you can check in `ShouldSkipPage` when called with `InputPage.Id`.